# Does Python provide any libraries for textual relationship?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, text, sentiment-analysis

I have a word, let us say 'USA', and a textual document. I want to know if the document as whole is about 'USA' or not. The word 'USA' could be mentioned like 100 or 1000 times in the document, but by the end of the day the document might be talking about China.

I went through sentiment analysis libraries in Python, but these libraries will return only if the the doc mentioned the word in a positive, negative, or neutral way.

I can also count how many times the word mentioned, and the similarity between the word and each word in the doc, but still do not know how to tell if the doc as whole is about the mentioned word or not.

Is there any libraries in python to do this, or any APIs ?

Comment: check topic modeling in here: https://textacy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @MedAli Thank you, I will take a look at it.

Comment: I think the code given in this link might come in handy. Use this code to summerize a text in one sentence which has the most word frequency. https://github.com/assafelovic/nlp_url_summarizer

Answer (score 1):

There's not any really good complete solution libraries for this. You'll probably want to use something like NLTK for the word stemming and analysis (http://www.nltk.org). Stemming is the following: "Ferrari -> sports car -> car -> transportation", this enables you to see the "base" concept of a word.

Then you'll probably want to do some sort of TF/IDF analysis to determine exactly what the document is about. This will help you determine which words are important (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html).

A good tutorial on TF/IDF can be seen here: http://stevenloria.com/finding-important-words-in-a-document-using-tf-idf/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will take a look!